# Interlacing Suleĭmanova spectra

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials, sp.spectral-theory, nonnegative-matrices

A set of real numbers $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \}$, $n \geq 1$, is called a *Suleĭmanova spectrum* if it contains exactly one positive value and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \geq 0$. (It is [well-known](http://repository.uwyo.edu/ela/vol31/iss1/22/) that any such set is the spectrum of an entry-wise $n$-by-$n$ nonnegative matrix).

Let $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \}$ and $\{\hat{\lambda}_1, \dots, \hat{\lambda}_{n+1} \}$ be Suleĭmanova spectra such that
$$\hat{\lambda}_1 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \hat{\lambda}_2 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \dots \leq \hat{\lambda}_n \leq 0 \leq \lambda_n \leq \hat{\lambda}_{n+1}$$ 
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \hat{\lambda}_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \geq 0.$$

Now let
$$ f(t) = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (t - \hat{\lambda}_i) $$ 
and
$$ g(t) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (t - {\lambda}_i).$$

In the first-edition of Horn-and-Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*, the interlacing-assumption was used  to show that $f(\lambda_i)/g'(\lambda_i) \leq 0$, $1\leq i\leq n$ (p. 188).

Let
$$ y_i := 
\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{-f(\lambda_i)/g'(\lambda_i)}, & 1\leq i \leq n-1; \\
\sqrt{-f(\lambda_i)/g'(\lambda_i)}, & i=n; 
\end{cases}$$

Experimental evidence suggests that $\{ y_i \mid 1\leq i \leq n\}$ is a Suleĭmanova spectrum, but I am having difficulty proving that $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \geq 0$.